# Azure mobile apps - node.js - how to declare global variables?

Tags: node.js, azure

Azure mobile apps - node.js - how to declare global variables, that can be used in easy APIs?

Comment: Please explain in detail what do you mean by global variable with context, and an example on how you will use it?

Comment: I wanted to call other apis within Easy API through request.post('api/apiName'), but thats not working. However, if I use request.post('https://xxxx.azurewebsites.net/api/apiName'), its working. So, I was thinking of storing the url string 'https://xxxx.azurewebsites.net' as a global variable and append it where required. Hope this gives you the context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can declare global variables using the keyword global.

in your app.js

```
global.urlprefix = 'xxxx.azurewebsites.net';
```

in your other js files just do this.

```
request.post(global.urlprefix+'/api/apiName')
```